# Update MySQL Localhost to Server MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, server, database-replication

I want to update my localhost MySQL to my server side MySQL

When I connected to the Internet, update the database in localhost with the database on the server, but if there is no internet, localhost will continue to work and when the internet comes back, I want to do the same thing again.

I can update between 2 servers with MySQL replication, but I want my localhost database to be updated when connected to the internet with the database on the server.

Comment: Define: "connected to the Internet". As far as your computer's TCP/IP stack is concerned, there's no difference between your LAN and the Internet.

Comment: Try to connect to live server with a specific timeout. If this fails, fallback to localhost.

Comment: How can i update localhost MySQL with server side MySQL?

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: This is a PHP project.